# Angularjs $decorate directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I'm trying to decorate Angular Material directive and have a problem with Controller prototype functions:

```js
$provide.decorator('mdChipsDirective', ['$delegate', '$controller', function($delegate, $controller) {
  var directive = $delegate[0];
  var ctrlName = directive.controller;

  directive.scope.minChips = "@mdMinChips";

  directive.controller = function($scope, $attrs, $mdConstant, $log, $element, $timeout, $mdUtil) {

    var controller = $controller(ctrlName, {
      $scope: $scope,
      $attrs: $attrs,
      $mdConstant: $mdConstant,
      $log: $log,
      $element: $element,
      $timeout: $timeout,
      $mdUtil: $mdUtil
    }, true);

    console.log("controller", controller);
    return controller;
  }
  console.log('directive', directive)
  return $delegate;
}]);
```

My addition parameters in scope work fine but I recieve errors that methods from library not a functions. As I have understood in this way I'm rewriting native Controller prototype methods. What I'm doing wrong and how to just extend Controller?